# Html translation and links width Microsoft Cognitive Services Translator API

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator

When translating html I pass these parameters but the href of the  tags are not traced
That's normal?

@param '&textType=html&from=es&to=es'

Answer (score 1):

Translator will not modify the HREF. If you wanted to adjust the URL for different languages, you will need to do that separately.

If you have control of the web server the HREF links to, you could have your server listen to the client's accept-language and render the content of the appropriate language. With this setup, all client languages can use the same HREF.